# Is it possible to receive int/float implementations of a generic interface?

Tags: c#, generics

Assuming I have the following classes

```
public interface ISomeGenericInterface<out T>
{
...
}

public class IntImplementation : ISomeGenericInterface<int>
{
...
}

public class FloatImplementation : ISomeGenericInterface<float>
{
...
}
```

Is it somehow possible to receive both as a valid parameter?

I know one option is to add a base interface that is non-generic, but that would expose many more implementations vs. just exposing int/float as valid parameters.

```
public void ReceiveIntOrFloat(ISomeGenericInterface<?> intOrFloat)
{
...
}
```

Comment: This smells like an X/Y Problem - What is your actual end-goal, here?

Comment: Also, variant generic interfaces (e.g. `ISomething<in T>` and `ISomething<out T>`) only support covariance/contravariance when `T` is a reference-type, but `int` and `float` are both value-types - so that interface will always behave as an invariant interface (which is unfortunate as it would be useful when working with value-types that have safe implicit conversions).

Comment: Basically I have an `IValueProvider<T>` interface which is used throughout my system, and I want to be able to mix and match float/int ones all the while enforcing the actual int/float restrictions on each implementation

Comment: "and I want to be able to mix and match float/int ones" - I don't understand why you would want to do that because `float` and `int` are not really compatible at all: they represent completely different things (I know `Int32` is implicitly convertible to `Single`, but I feel that's a design-error in .NET because it's unsafe, e.g. `Single f = Int32.MaxValue` results in information-loss, and of course, `Single` is _not_ implicitly convertible back to `Int32`).

Comment: Even if you can do this, would there be anything to do in the method? `ISomeGenericInterface<int>` and `ISomeGenericInterface<float>` would be incompatible types, so you cannot reuse any code on them.

Comment: If you want to be able to mix and match `float` and `int`, how will you know what to do with it? What operations do you propose to do on them having not known exactly what type it is?

Comment: @Charlieface To be fair, _in general_, that's not a problem: just use a union-type. C# doesn't have built-in support for union-types, but F# does, and C# users can also use [this amazing library](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf) as a quick-and-dirty solution with only a few warts.

Comment: @Ron Just to confirm: you're wanting to express a type-union of `IMyInterface<Int32> | IMyInterface<Single>` - and **not** `IMyInterface<Int32 | Single>`, right? Both are possible in C# today, but they're very different things from each other and your question isn't exactly clear...

Comment: Currently, I'm using an adapter class that translates int-float value providers back and forth and it basically floats/clamps before converting to the wanted value type. I wanted to achieve something similar without having to wrap it with an adapter every time.

Comment: @Dai to be honest I'm not familiar with type-unions.

Comment: @Ron If you're always "clamping" `Single` values to `Int32` values then why not just use `Int32` everywhere?

Comment: @Ron https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union

Comment: @Ron (Using TypeScript notation), the declaration "`IMyInterface<Int32> | IMyInterface<Single> x`" means that `x` is a single instance of *either* `IMyInterface<Int32>` **or** `IMyInterface<Single>` - while "`IMyInterface<Int32 | Single> x` means that `x` is a single object instance of `IMyInterface<T>` such that every `T`-typed member or parameter can _always_ be either `Int32` or `Single`.

Comment: @Ron My immediate interpretation of your post suggests that you just want `IMyInterface<Int32> | IMyInterface<Single> x`, however after you posted more details I'm unsure - we really need an solid example of the problem you're trying to overcome...

Comment: @Dai I'll add some more information in a few minutes, thanks

Comment: While adding more info I came to the conclusion that you are right and this is not a correct solution, I'll keep using adapters, even though they are bothersome to use - they are explicit and communicate the conversation that happens between types.